# QWebkit missing on MXE crosscompiler and Qt 4

Tags: qt4, qwebkit, mxe

I did the installation of the MXE crosscompiler and I am trying to make an app for Windows on Linux. But an error where said there was no QWeb compiling emerged. I checked this and there doesn't exist such component compiled Qt in the MXE. I want to know how to get QWeb for MXE?

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like it gets built. You can always migrate to Qt 5 though, where you'd build it with this command:

```
make qtwebkit
```

Ensure to switch the *master* branch, since it's not available in *stable*.

Comment: Well, in master i find a 'mxe/src/qtwebkit.mk' file, and i compiled with 'make qt' and QWebkit not yet appeared.